# Send File via libssh (ssh_scp_push_file && ssh_scp_write)

Tags: c++, scp, libssh

Disclaimer: **I'm googling my way through this**

- Using C++
- Both ends are Linux
- I can see the SSH connection on the far end via TCPDUMP
- No build errors or return codes other than 0 (debug says its all good)
- TCPDUMP doesn't look like its transferring enough data (it is a 2MB file*)
- Connect / Authenticate / Authorize are happening properly as far as I can tell

When i go to the far end looking for the file that was supposedly copied over, it doesn't exist.  I've tried updatedb & locate "file", but it's nowhere to be found.

Thank you in advance for any insight possible!

SSH Functions (auth & connect) cleared out for "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example" since they seem to be working fine*

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <boost/system/error_code.hpp>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/stat.h>
#define LIBSSH_STATIC 1
#include <libssh/libssh.h>

using namespace std;

int sourcePull(void)
{
    CURL *curl; 
    FILE *fp;
    CURLcode res;
    char *url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/firehol/blocklist-ipsets/master/firehol_level1.netset";
    char outfilename[FILENAME_MAX] = "fireHOL";
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl)
    {
        fp = fopen(outfilename, "wb");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, NULL);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return 0;
}

int sourceParse()
{
    //Regex for IP's in sourcePull result
    ifstream infile("fireHOL");
    string ipAddress;
    boost::regex expr1("^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$");
    boost::regex expr2("^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(\\/([0-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-2]))$");
    boost::smatch matches;

        while (infile >> ipAddress)
        {
            if (boost::regex_match(ipAddress, matches, expr1)) 
            {
                ofstream checkpoint;
                checkpoint.open("samp_batch.txt", ios::out | ios::app);
                checkpoint << "add -t 86400 -a d -l r -o icewall ip -s " << ipAddress << endl;
                checkpoint << "add -t 86400 -a r -l r -o icewall ip -d " << ipAddress << endl;
            }

            if (boost::regex_match(ipAddress, matches, expr2))
            {
                ofstream checkpoint;
                checkpoint.open("samp_batch.txt", ios::out | ios::app);
                checkpoint << "add -t 86400 -a d -l r -o icewall ip -s " << ipAddress << endl;
                checkpoint << "add -t 86400 -a r -l r -o icewall ip -d " << ipAddress << endl;
            }

        }

        ofstream terminate;
        terminate.open("samp_batch.txt", ios::out | ios::app);
        terminate << "EOF";

    return 0;
}

int fileSize()
{
    int size;
    streampos begin, end;
    ifstream inputFile("samp_batch", ios::binary);
    begin = inputFile.tellg();
    inputFile.seekg(0, ios::end);
    end = inputFile.tellg();
    inputFile.close();
    return size;
}

int ssh()
{
    ssh_session my_ssh_session;
    ssh_scp scp;
    int port = 22;
    int rc;
    int method;
    char password[128] = { 0 };
    char *banner;
    //open session & set options
    my_ssh_session = ssh_new();
    if (my_ssh_session == NULL)
        exit(-1);
    ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_HOST, "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX");
    ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_PORT, &port);
    ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_USER, "security");

    //connect to server
    rc = ssh_connect(my_ssh_session);
    if (rc != SSH_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error connecting to host: %s\n", ssh_get_error(my_ssh_session));
        ssh_free(my_ssh_session);
        exit(-1);
    }

    //verify the servers identity
    if (verify_knownHost(my_ssh_session) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "unkown host\n");
        ssh_disconnect(my_ssh_session);
        ssh_free(my_ssh_session);
        exit(-1);
    }


    // Try to authenticate
    rc = ssh_userauth_none(my_ssh_session, NULL);
    if (rc == SSH_AUTH_ERROR) {
        error(my_ssh_session);
        return rc;
    }

    method = ssh_auth_list(my_ssh_session);
    while (rc != SSH_AUTH_SUCCESS) {
        // Try to authenticate with public key first
        if (method & SSH_AUTH_METHOD_PUBLICKEY) {
            rc = ssh_userauth_autopubkey(my_ssh_session, NULL);
            if (rc == SSH_AUTH_ERROR) {
                error(my_ssh_session);
                return rc;
            }
            else if (rc == SSH_AUTH_SUCCESS) {
                break;
            }
        }

    return rc;

    //SCP samp_batch file here
    const int length = fileSize();
    const char *fileName = "samp_batch";


    ifstream inputFile(fileName);
    constexpr size_t bufferSize = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
    unique_ptr<char[]> buffer(new char[bufferSize]);
    const void* cvp = &buffer;

    rc = ssh_scp_push_file(scp, "samp_batch", length, 0777);
    if (rc != SSH_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open remote file: %s\n", ssh_get_error(my_ssh_session));
        ssh_free(my_ssh_session);
        exit(-1);

    }

    while (inputFile)
    {

        inputFile.read(buffer.get(), 1024 * 1024 * 1024);

        rc = ssh_scp_write(scp, cvp, bufferSize);
        if (rc != SSH_OK)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Cant write to remote file: %s\n", ssh_get_error(my_ssh_session));
            ssh_free(my_ssh_session);
            exit(-1);

        }
    }

    return SSH_OK;

    ////execute remote command here


    //ssh_free(my_ssh_session);
}

int main()
{

    sourcePull();
    sourceParse();
    ssh();


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why does `fileSize()` not take the file name as a parameter? As it is now, you are looking at two different files. One for get the size and one to read from.

Comment: I have it "coded in" since is going to be set on a chron job & left alone, but that was a mistake, thank you.  edited post to reflect as it still isn't working :(.  It's also a constant filename that wont change*

Comment: Could you post a [MCVE]?

Comment: `rc = ssh_scp_write(scp, cvp, bufferSize);` You're writing out the entire buffer here. You should just write the number of bytes that you read from the input file. Also considering your buffer is 1GB in size, if you're not seeing that much traffic through tcpdump, that suggests that your program isn't even reaching this point. And do you need such a large buffer? Anything over 32k-64k is probably a waste.

Comment: edited w/ more details @Jonas

Comment: @Kenster it's a 2MB file so deff going overkill on the buffer then.  Changed the function to "rc = ssh_scp_write(scp, cvp, length);"  & saw no change, everything looks the same.

Comment: Why don't you use the `<libssh/libsshpp.hpp>` header which provides a C++ wrapper for `<libssh/libssh>`?

Comment: @datell I wasn't aware of it....I'll have to check it out :)

Comment: Don't expect to much! It is horribly documentated, a lot of functions can be found in the source code but not in the doxygen documentation. And it is really just a wrapper like `mycppfunc(){return mycfunc();}`. It won't solve your problem, I was just wondering.

Comment: Would still like to know why the current code isn't working**

Comment: @datell lol tyvm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue w/ of course, more reading...

I was not actually initializing the SCP subsystem "within" the SSH system.

By adding in;

```
    scp = ssh_scp_new(my_ssh_session, SSH_SCP_WRITE, "/");
    if (scp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error allocating scp session: %s\n", ssh_get_error(my_ssh_session));
        return SSH_ERROR;
    }
    rc = ssh_scp_init(scp);
    if (rc != SSH_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error initializing scp session: %s\n", ssh_get_error(my_ssh_session));
        ssh_scp_free(scp);
        return rc;
    }
```

above my push/write functions, I was able to get the SCP subsystem to "start".  Haven't gotten her functioning yet (SCP Status Code 1d not valid) error now, but i at least know scp is "awake" at this point...